# C# XNA 4.0 Fullscreen Mouse Moves Into Second Monitor

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

The heading just about says it all. I derive from the XNA Game class, and set the IsMouseVisible = true. I have a dual screen setup with the secondary display being extended from the primary. I set my game to fullscreen mode (GraphicsDeviceManager.IsFullScreen = true). All works fine and fullscreen mode is initialized. The only problem I have is that the mouse does not stay bound within the fullscreen game. As soon as it reaches the edge of the fullscreen game, it seamlessly moves over onto the secondary monitor. Is this expected bahaviour?

I do a Mouse.GetState() to retrieve mouse info every frame on the same thread in which my game runs.

I have even tried setting Mouse.WindowHandle = GameWindowHandle before every call to GetState, but it does not change anything.

Any ideas? Or is this expected behaviour and I need to clamp the mouse to the fullscreen area myself?

Regards,
Riaan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, exactly, clamp your mouse to the screen that you want it to stay on.  This is similar to an approach that I (and many others) use when I implement sprite cursors for my games.  I hide the system mouse, and clamp it to the center of the screen so that it doesn't show up on other monitors.

The only downside is that you have to un-clamp your mouse if you minimize the game, etc.  Otherwise it stays stuck, which can be really annoying.

Comment: A.R. Thank you for the reply, so this means I cannot use system icons for my mouse? Atm I just load ico files (some of them animated) and it is displayed automatically by the system cursor, convenient! Could I still do this or would it have to be put into images and displayed with spritebatch at the hidden mouse's position...

Comment: No, you can use the system icons, but only if the system mouse is visible.  However, you may wind up needing your own sprites if you want to do non-system stuff, like adjust the alpha, use a large bitmap, etc.  In that case, the system cursor gets hidden, and yours is used instead.